# Solving differential equation with three products

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this differential equation when $y(0)=0$.

$$\frac {dy}{dt}=k\left(n_1-{\frac{y}{2}}\right)^2\left(n_2-{\frac{y}{2}}\right)^2\left(n_3-{\frac{3y}{4}}\right)^3$$

Where
$$k=6.22*10^{-19}$$
$$n_1=2$$
$$n_2=2$$
$$n_3=3$$

So far I've tried moving everything on one side
$$\frac{1}{\left(n_1-{\frac{y}{2}}\right)^2\left(n_2-{\frac{y}{2}}\right)^2\left(n_3-{\frac{3y}{4}}\right)^3}dx=k 
*dt$$ but I don't know where to go from there. Should I turn them into $\frac{1}{u^2v^2w^3}dy=k*dt$ and go ahead, or...?

Comment: Did you notice that the first and second factor are the same? And that all factors are multiples of $(4-y)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the provided constants your DE can be written as
$$
y'=-k\left(\frac12\right)^3\left(\frac34\right)^3(y-4)^7
$$
which has a solution
$$
(y-4)^{-6}=(y_0-4)^{-6}+c(t-t_0)
$$
where $C$ assembles all the above constant factors and the $6$ from the differentiation of $(y-4)^{-6}$.